# django-jsonforms how to limit how many fields can add from object properties collapsable?

Tags: json, django, jsonschema, django-jsonfield, jsoneditor

Is there a way so set a range or limit on how many fields a person can add from the object properties collapsable? or any docs on how to configure it? I looked at the docs I could find, but.

```
options = {'additionalProperties': True  }
form = JSONSchemaForm(schema=jsonschema, options=options, ajax=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't effext the object properties collapsable, but works in the object properties. jsonschemas aren't bound thing, apparently.

```
    {
     "title": "Product",
   "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
      "tags": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "type": "string"
          },
          "minItems": 0,
          "maxItems": 2,
          "uniqueItems": True
      }
  }
}
```